# How to align element inside of many wrapped divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `row` div which contains 1 div called `horizontal-form`, inside this `horizontal-form` contains other two divs, called `form-group`, and inside this `form-group` I have another div, called `input-group` which contains 1 `a` tag and 1 `span` text.I would like to align these span to the most right position. I tried to use `class = pull-right` but then it aligned to the right position but compared to the nearest div, here is the `input-group`. Can anyone show me how can I align the span to any position that I wish, for example here i would like to align it to the right position compared to the div `row` or `horizontal-form`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="horizontal-form">
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group subQuestionsLabel" data-toggle="collapse" >
        <a href="javascript:">FirstItem</a>
        <span class="button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i> </button>
        </span>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group subQuestionsLabel" data-toggle="collapse" >
        <a href="javascript:">SecondItem</a>
        <span class="button">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i> </button>
        </span>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened beacause of `"input-group"` class as it has `"display:table;"` property in css.

So There is two ways to resolve this.

1. Remove this class
2. Overwrite css for this `class` as `"display:block"`

Comment: Thanks Sadikali, may i ask one more question, is it possible to put a border box which contains these two buttons?

Comment: i mean a vertical box to contain these two buttons

Comment: Yes it is possible, but make sure that "vertical box" should not contain "display:table" property.

Comment: could you please show me how can i do it?, I already change the code like you said above: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19195/

Comment: Do you want this two buttons in one row?

Comment: no, they are in two rows like they are now, but I want to ask a box to bound them

Comment: There is already box classname "horizontal-form" to button these two buttons.

Comment: sorry maybe I make you misundertand, I would like to keep the a tag also,  like http://postimg.org/image/wmb1rxv4z/, very sorry Sadikali

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are asking its not the right way to do it as i see in your code because you are using bootstrap and bootstrap logic doesnt work like this. If you need your span align whatever you want dont put it inside the `div` with `horizontal-form` class and `form-group` class. In this case if i understood it well to align it right just apply `float: right;` to the `span`.

Comment: sorry Agolli, I dont really get your idea, could you please explain me a bit clearer?

Comment: Did you tried to put span {float: right;} on your css ?